# Heroku + NestJs - Can't read config vars on serverside

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment, nestjs

Have run into an issue where my serverside call from my api folder is unable to read the config vars set on heroku.

Have tested and they appear fine on the clientside portion of my nestjs app.

Is there a specific prefix I need to use for config vars that will be used on the serverside?

Below is the current naming convention I am using on my app.

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_EMAIL
```

Comment: "next": "9.5.3" is the version I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, there was an issue with multiline config var not being formatted correctly.